# im trying to get the image from the item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to get the image selected from https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPEhl.png
to show on https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4rr2.png

the code for both parts is in js and i cant work it out

```
var CartCount;

        $('.image').on('click', function () {
            $("#cart").load(location.href + " #cart");

            $('.carticon').show("fast");

            CartCount = CartCount + 1;
            var item = $(this).attr('id');
            var label = $(this).attr('label');
            var count = $(this).attr('count');
            var price = $(this).attr('price');

            $("#" + item).hide();
            

            $.post('http://esx-kr-advanced-shops/putcart', JSON.stringify({item: item, price : price, label : label, count : count, id : id}), function( cb ) {

                $('#cart').html('');

            var i;
                for (i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) { 

                    $('#cart').append(
                        `<div class = "cartitem" label = ${cb[i].label} count = ${cb[i].count} price = ${cb[i].price}>
                        img src="${cb[i].}"width="100" height="100"
                        <h6>${cb[i].label}</h4>
                        <h6>$${cb[i].price} per item</h4>
                        <h6>In stock: ${cb[i].count}</h4>
                        <input type="text" id = ${cb[i].item} count = ${cb[i].count} class = "textareas" placeholder = "Amount"></textarea>
                        </div>`
                            );
                        };

                        $('#cart').append(
                        `<br><br>
                        <button class = "button" id = "buybutton" style = "position: absolute; right: 15px; top: 5px;">Purchase</button>
                        <button class = "button" id = "back" style = "position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 5px;">Back</button>
                        `
                    );
                });
        });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no its a script of fivem forums there isnt supposed to be an image there im trying to get it to show one

Comment: Try to learn how to construct your questions before posting next time. Welcome to stackoverflow. Also, do you have any reason for JSON.stringifying your post data? You're already using a library that handles such things intelligently, unless if your set the processData flag to false.

Comment: well i have learning difficulties and it hard to work our sometimes how to word things

Comment: Check my answer below and make all the necessary corrections. If you still can't get it to work, add `console.log(cb)` inside your ajax callback function to see if you really have a response.

Answer (score 0):

Check your callback markup for errors:

1. Your img tag is not a tag
2. Your input ended with a closing `</textarea>`
3. Your `<h6>` price per item has double `$$`
4. Ensure that you quote the `id` of the input field
5. Etc.

```
$('#cart').append(
     `<div class = "cartitem" label = ${cb[i].label} count = ${cb[i].count} price = ${cb[i].price}>
        <img src="${cb[i].img}.jpg" width="100" height="100">
        <h6>${cb[i].label}</h4>
        <h6>${cb[i].price} per item</h4>
        <h6>In stock: ${cb[i].count}</h4>
        <input type="text" id = "${cb[i].item}" count = ${cb[i].count} class = "textareas" placeholder = "Amount">
    </div>`
     );
};

$('#cart').append(
     `<br><br>
      <button class = "button" id = "buybutton" style = "position: absolute; right: 15px; top: 5px;">Purchase</button>
      <button class = "button" id = "back" style = "position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 5px;">Back</button>`
);
```